# What can I do to return to the login screen in the home screen with this syntax in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    { user ? (
      <Stack.Screen name="Home">
        {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    ): (
      <>
      
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
        
      </>
      
    )} 
  </Stack.Navigator>
  
</NavigationContainer>
```

I need in here <Stack.Screen name="Home">
{props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
</Stack.Screen> go back to here <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />

btw my initial screen is home

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should write a helper class for independent navigation.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

class NavigationService{
    _navigator = null;
    currentRoute = null;
    isNavigated = false;

    setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
        _navigator = navigatorRef;
    }
  
    navigate(routeName, params) {
        _navigator.dispatch(
           NavigationActions.navigate({
              type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
              routeName,
              params,
           })
        );
       }

      setCurrentRoute(routName){
         this.currentRoute = routName;
      }

      setNavigated(status){
        this.isNavigated = status;
      }
 }


// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

const Navigation = new NavigationService();

export default Navigation;
```

Then, you import this class on your Home page.

```
import NavigationHelper from './NavigationService'; // Path can change according to you
const HomePage = () => {
NavigationHelper.navigate('Login');
return(//Sometihng);
}
```